# c# Parsing XML issue

Tags: c#, .net, xml, silverlight, xml-serialization

I am using this code to try and read this XML below, but it is not read anything in the foreach loop and skipping that. Thanks.

C#

```
 XElement _xml;
 _xml = XElement.Parse(PostResult);
 foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("ServiceDelivery")
                                .Element("StopMonitoringDelivery")
                                .Elements("MonitoredStopVisit"))
          {
             StopFeed _item = new StopFeed();
             _item.A= value.Element("PublishedLineName").Value;
             _item.B = value.Element("DirectionName").Value;

              listBox1.Items.Add(_item);
           }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>    
<Siri version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/">
<ServiceDelivery>
    <ResponseTimestamp>2011-10-04T11:45:36.415+01:00</ResponseTimestamp>
    <ResponseMessageIdentifier>1d8bc237-2df6-43e6-af56-c750d3089eb6</ResponseMessageIdentifier>
    <StopMonitoringDelivery version="1.0">
        <ResponseTimestamp>2011-10-04T11:45:36.415+01:00</ResponseTimestamp>
        <RequestMessageRef>1</RequestMessageRef>
        <MonitoredStopVisit>
            <RecordedAtTime>2011-10-04T11:45:36.412+01:00</RecordedAtTime>
            <MonitoringRef>020035057</MonitoringRef>
            <MonitoredVehicleJourney>
                <FramedVehicleJourneyRef>
                    <DataFrameRef>-</DataFrameRef>
                    <DatedVehicleJourneyRef>-</DatedVehicleJourneyRef>
                </FramedVehicleJourneyRef>
                <VehicleMode>bus</VehicleMode>
                <PublishedLineName>28</PublishedLineName>
                <DirectionName>blahblah</DirectionName>
                <OperatorRef>153</OperatorRef>
                <MonitoredCall>
                    <AimedDepartureTime>2011-10- 04T11:48:00.000+01:00</AimedDepartureTime>
                </MonitoredCall>
            </MonitoredVehicleJourney>
        </MonitoredStopVisit>
    </StopMonitoringDelivery>
</ServiceDelivery>
</Siri>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `.Elements("Siri")` before `"ServiceDelivery"`

Comment: Yes, I tried that with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot the namespace. Have a look at [XNamespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx)

```
XNamespace xn= "http://www.siri.org.uk/";

foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements(xn+ "ServiceDelivery")
                            .Element(xn+ "StopMonitoringDelivery")
                            .Elements(xn+ "MonitoredStopVisit"))
{
      ....
}
```

Comment: It is not working this way - `XmlNamespaceManager` is the solution for handling xml namespaces (http://blog.stevex.net/xpath-and-xml-namespaces/)

Comment: @KarelFrajtak. You're wrong. This is Linq XML http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The root element is Siri.

Either use:

```
XElement value in _xml.Root.Elements("ServiceDelivery")
                            .Element("StopMonitoringDelivery")
                            .Elements("MonitoredStopVisit"))
```

or

```
XElement value in _xml.Element("Siri")
                            .Elements("ServiceDelivery")
                            .Element("StopMonitoringDelivery")
                            .Elements("MonitoredStopVisit"))
```

/B

Answer (score 0):

try `_xml.Elements("//ServiceDelivery")` or `_xml.Elements("Siri/ServiceDelivery")`, you forgot that your `ServiceDelivery` node is child of `Siri` node.

Or maybe the XML namespace is the problem, check this [page](http://blog.stevex.net/xpath-and-xml-namespaces/) and see how `XmlNamespaceManager` can be used.